# Commutant of positive invertible operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, functional-calculus

‎Let‎ ‎$ H‎^{N} $ be a ‎$ N $-dimensional Hilbert space, ‎$ S, T‎\in ‎L(H‎^{N})‎. $ Suppose that ‎‎$ T $ ‎is invertible and ‎positive ‎operator ‎$‎‎(<Tx,x>‎\geq0 ) ‎$‎ such that ‎$ ST=TS. $ I‎ ‎can't ‎prove ‎that‎ ‎$ ST‎^{r}‎=T‎^{r}S$‎, for ay real number ‎$ r‎\in‎ \mathbb {R}$‎. We know since ‎$ T $ ‎is ‎positive and invertible‎, then ‎$ T‎^{r}‎ $ ‎is ‎well-defined ‎for ‎any ‎real ‎number‎  ‎$ r‎\in‎ \mathbb {R}$‎.

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Comment: @Chee Han it is for any real number ‎$ r‎\in‎ \mathbb {R}$ not integer number.

Comment: Oh, oppss, didn't see that.

Comment: How exactly do you define $T^r$?

Comment: @Meowdog

By holomorphic functional calculus, ‎$ ‎T‎^{r}‎‎ $‎ is defined.

Comment: Alright. Use that there exists a polynomial $g$ with degree $\leq N$ such that $g(T) = T^r$.